# How to work with value and key in associative array

Tags: php, arrays

Is it possible I have two array

```
array1 = Array
(
    [14] => 0
    [15] => 1
    [16] => 2
    [17] => 3
    [18] => 4
    [19] => 5
    [20] => 6
    [21] => 7
    [22] => 8
    [23] => 9
);

array2 = 
    Array
(
    [0] => 'value'
    [1] => 'value'
    [2] => 'value'
    [3] => 'value'
    [4] => 'value'
    [5] => 'value'
    [6] => 'value'
    [7] => 'value'
    [8] => 'value'
    [9] => 'value'
);
```

I want to make it:

```
array3 = array( [14]=>'value',[15]=>'value',[16]=>'value',[17]=>'value',[18]=>'value',[19]=>'value',[20]=>'value',[21]=>'value',[22]=>'value',[23]=>'value'));
```

Comment: @anantkumarsingh Just wrong! This will not produce what OP wants. He just simply have to use `array_combine`, but since he wants the keys from the first array as keys, he has to use `array_keys`, e.g. `array_combine(array_keys($arr1), $arr2)`

Comment: sorry my mistake.thanks for telling.

Comment: `$array3 = array_combine(array_keys($arr1),$array2); print_r($array3);`

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this.

```
<?php 

$array1 = Array
(
    "14" => 0,
    "15" => 1,
    "16" => 2,
    "17" => 3,
    "18" => 4,
    "19" => 5,
    "20" => 6,
    "21" => 7,
    "22" => 8,
    "23" => 9
);

$array2 = 
    Array
(
    "0" => 'value',
    "1" => 'value',
    "2" => 'value',
    "3" => 'value',
    "4" => 'value',
    "5" => 'value',
    "6" => 'value',
    "7" => 'value',
    "8" => 'value',
    "9" => 'value'
);

//Solution #1
foreach($array1 AS $key => $value){
    $array1[$key] = $array2[$value];
}

//solution #2 , thnx to the comments
$array1 = array_combine(array_keys($array1), $array2);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($array1);

?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [14] => value
    [15] => value
    [16] => value
    [17] => value
    [18] => value
    [19] => value
    [20] => value
    [21] => value
    [22] => value
    [23] => value
)
```

Comment: array_keys with array_combine is much better solution

Comment: @robert Edited my answer, Can I ask why `array_combine`is better?

Comment: because oftenly using build in function that does the same things as your wrote is better. Do some performance test you will see. And also writing function that is already written and works well is bad habit IMO.